# How do i increment the number that prefixes the .jpg according the NUM_PHOTOS for each item.id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Thanks to this site, I now have json data returning from server, nicely poplating my page.

One of the fields returned is `NUM_PHOTOS`.  There is at least 1 photo for each `item.id`.

But the actual photos aren't in the json data, they are in a diff directory and all increment and begin with `'item.id'+/1.jpg` up to and depending on the `NUM_PHOTOS` that exist for that particular item.

e.g. for item '20090' there are 5 photos, in a seperate directory as:  `/20090/1.jpg, 20090/2.jpg, etc.` up to however many photos there are. 
How do i increment the number that prefixes the `.jpg` according the the NUM_PHOTOS for each `item.id?`

I have dynamically populated the flexsider with the first 3 images for every 'item.id' using the code below, but of course the number of photos will vary and I am stuck on what is needed to append the prefix of the `.jpg'`s that are in the `NUM_PHOTOS` for each `item.id.`

```
$('.flexslider .slides').append('<li><img src="http://url/data/listing/pics/' + item.id     + '/1.jpg"></li>');           
$('.slides').append('<li><img src="http://www.url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/' + item.id     + '/2.jpg"></li>');
$('.slides').append('<li><img src="http://www.url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/' + item.id     + '/3.jpg"></li>');
}
```

I have tried several techniques, but as a total beginner I need a bit of a hand..

```
JS is: 
 $('#detailsPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
    var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
    $.getJSON('http://www.url.co.nz/feeds/json_detail.php?id='+id, displayItem);
    });
    function displayItem(data) {
var listing = data.item;

$('#id').text(listing.id + ', ' + listing.suburb + ', ' +listing.district); 
$('#Title').text(listing.title);
$('#numberPhotos').text(listing.num_photos);
$('#price').text('Price Approx:   ' + '$' + listing.price );

// how do i auto increment the .jpg according the 'num_photos' field returned from json?
// ?????  if (listing.num_photos???????) {


$('.flexslider .slides').append('<li><img src="http://www.url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/' +     listing.id + '/1.jpg"></li>');
$('.slides').append('<li><img src="http://www.url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/' + listing.id     + '/2.jpg"></li>');
$('.slides').append('<li><img src="http://www.url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/' + listing.id     + '/3.jpg"></li>');
}

function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
```

Comment: Show the Json and the script you have so far, please.

Comment: Since you have NUM_PHOTOS, why dont you loop?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < data.NUM_PHOTOS; i++){...}

Comment: Thanks! When I alert(i) it alerts the right number of pictures for that listing.id, but when i use this append statement, nothing shows.
                                            $('.flexslider.slides').append('<li><img src="http://url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/' + employee.id + ' / ' + i + '.jpg"></li>');

Comment: You're a star.  Thanks so much I got the append working, just the flexslider is slow and doesn't show till refresh.  Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to count the number of id which is coming in the JSON data.

just before this line

```
var listing = data.item;
```

once you count then place the below code inside the loop that's it

```
for(i=0;i<counted_value;i++){
   var listing = data.item;
   $('.slides').append('<li><img src="http://www.url.co.nz/data/listing/pics/'+ listing.id +'/2.jpg"></li>');
}
```

If you don't know how to count so first print the data in console and check for data format and try to print the count in a test file